# Running Sails app in Production mode takes longer time to load

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Sails app when deploying on production server hangs up giving spawning error on passenger server the same thing works fine in dev env.The task that takes longest time is grunt uglify and the app crashes.What is the solution for it or should disable grunt hook on production environment.

Comment: Can you show us the error ?

Comment: `Starting ORM...
pubsub hook loaded successfully.
Grunt :: &#27;[4mRunning &quot;clean:dev&quot; (clean) task&#27;[24m
Grunt :: &#27;[4mRunning &quot;uglify:dist&quot; (uglify) task&#27;[24m
</pre>

age/Hel/Req/CheckoutSession.cpp:252 ]: [Client 1-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 6ac17253. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
[ 2015-08-24 16:08:06.5774 29680/7f9bd1b9f700 Ser/Server.h:931 ]: [Client 1-1] Disconnecting client with error: client socket write error: Broken pipe this is the server log on our staging server`

Answer (score 3):

You can update the timeout of grunt by adding/editing config/grunt.js

```
module.exports.grunt = {
  _hookTimeout : 500000

};
```

Like this grunt have more time to uglify your files.

You can also remove the uglify task by editing tasks/register/prod.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt)
{
  grunt.registerTask('prod', ['compileAssets', 'concat', 'cssmin', 'sails-linker:prodJs', 'sails-linker:prodStyles', 'sails-linker:devTpl']);
};
```

Or you can use sails-generate-archive who create a production archive ready to deploy and your server will start in seconds. (but if you have a grunt timeout you need to do the first solution first).
https://github.com/jaumard/sails-generate-archive

Comment: Actually the server timeout on passenger is 60 sec default and sails grunt task takes usually 1.45 secs .what effect will it have if i remove uglify task?

Comment: Prod tasks take more time to process cause they concat every JS and CSS in one file. The uglify task take all you javascript files, minify and uglify them in one file "production.min.js". That's why by increase the timeout it have to pass on production. 
I never try to remove only the uglify task, maybe you have to also modify sails-linker to set /concat/production.css instead of /min/production.min.css cause it doesn't exist without uglify task

Comment: okk i will look into it!!Any other solution if there post it i will check them too.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution we have to increase the timeout of server in production environment so that the server provides enough time for grunt task to be executed.Another solution is as @jaumard specified to make the production ready archive so that your server will be up in few seconds in production environment also.